# AWS WordPress High Availability EFS, EC2 and MySQL database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-ec2, high-availability, amazon-efs

I'm building a Wordpress high availability service.  I know a little about Wordpress, but not sure how to get it working and setup for HA.   I've done reading from various articles, but not sure how tolerant Wordpress is when changes occur on one host and now the other host will react.

I'm starting with 2 EC2 instances, EFS(NFS) and RDS MySQL database.   The EFS is used to share the application configuration/data/content on both instances.  RDS MySQL database will be shared on both instances as well.   Does anyone see any hurdles with this design?   I'm wondering how Wordpress plugins gets updated on one host and if the other host will see the same updates dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

I used the same infrastructure design for a high traffic blog and it works like a charm.

> I've done reading from various articles, but not sure how tolerant Wordpress is when changes occur on one host and now the other host will react.

As long as your wordpress files are stored into EFS, all EC2 instances will be up-to-date.

Suggestions:

- Use CloudFront for serving your assets. Do not rely on EFS or you'll burn all your EFS burst credits.
- Use an Autoscaling Group for scaling up/down your instances.
- Strictly monitor the EFS burst/throughput credits using CloudWatch alarms. If you burn all your credits, your instances are not able to read from the EFS storage!

Comment: Thanks for the info and suggestions @Antonio!   I plan to use Cloudfront service in our design.    Glad you have this design working for you as it helps validate our idea. I also like the fact you've incorporated autoscaling; definitely will set that up as well.   I'm still curious about Wordpress changes...   How do you do upgrades to Wordpress "core and/or plugins" in an HA environment?  I assume you just do one host and the other host Wordpress service just needs to be restarted?

Comment: Your WordPress files will be stored in EFS. 
When you update/install a plugin, one of your EC2 instances will download the required files and save them into EFS. All the other EC2 instances will automatically fetch the new files from EFS.

If you want to be sure that all instances use the updated PHP files, you may reload the PHP-FPM processes (or just clear the opcode cache).